# Use File Browser to select FOLDER not FILE

Tags: scripting, import

I'd like to use Blender to visualize several things that I have in a folder. I am visualizing a dataset which might contain a pointcloud, a 3D model, among others. I'd like to be able to select the **dataset folder** and not an individual file or a set of files. In the `operator_file_import.py` file there seems to be a `filter_glob` property which might be the solution, but it's not clear for me if there is pattern to match folders only. Is this actually possible?

From the scripting template

````
class ImportSomeData(Operator, ImportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "import_test.some_data"  # important since its how bpy.ops.import_test.some_data is constructed
    bl_label = "Import Some Data"

    # ImportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".txt"

    # ---> IS THERE A FILTER TO SELECT FOLDERS?
    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="*.txt",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255,  # Max internal buffer length, longer would be clamped.
    )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator settings before calling.
    use_setting: BoolProperty(
        name="Example Boolean",
        description="Example Tooltip",
        default=True,
    )

    type: EnumProperty(
        name="Example Enum",
        description="Choose between two items",
        items=(
            ('OPT_A', "First Option", "Description one"),
            ('OPT_B', "Second Option", "Description two"),
        ),
        default='OPT_A',
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        return read_some_data(context, self.filepath, self.use_setting)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short snippet of how you can print out the currently opened directory in the console. You have to use the `directory` attribute and set the `filter_glob` to `""` to filter only directories.

```
import bpy

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator


class ImportSomeData(Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "import_test.some_data"
    bl_label = "Import Some Data"

    directory: StringProperty()

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255,  # Max internal buffer length, longer would be clamped.
    )
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.directory)
        return {"FINISHED"}

def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ImportSomeData.bl_idname, text="Text Import Operator")

bpy.utils.register_class(ImportSomeData)
bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)
```