# Selecting folders with bpy.context.window_manager.fileselect_add

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I am slightly confised by the UI behaviour for selecting a file within an operator.

I got things working thanks to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275510/use-file-browser-to-select-folder-not-file) answer but as far as ai can see the process is:

- select folders recursively by clicking the default button
- only if I click on the default button *without* any subfolder being selected I clos the modal and get the path of the selected folder

Is there a way to make this work ore intuitively? for example: double click recurses, and clicking on the default button selects?

Or is this the standard way for Blender and that's it?

Comment: what is `double click recurses, and clicking on the default button selects`?

Comment: This is the way the finder on Mac OS behaves when you navigate folders

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    directory : bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text=SimpleOperator.bl_label)


# Register and add to the "object" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Object Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```